# How to perform Prametric mixture cure modelling in R? Although semi-parametric modelling package is there called smcure

Tags: model, rstudio, rstudio-server, survival

How to perform Prametric mixture cure modelling in R? Although semi-parametric modelling package is there called smcure. But i need to model my data by parametric mixture cure model. Or can anyone suggest other statistical package to do the same. Thanks in advance